# Youtube API refresh token error 400 (OAuth2 error)

Tags: api, oauth, youtube, token

I was trying to get the data from youtube for data analysis and I followed this post: https://help.aolonnetwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/218079623-How-to-Create-Your-YouTube-API-Credentials

I got the client key and secret key but having trouble with the refresh token. 
When I tried to get the token at oauthplayground [here](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) with my client key and secret key, I got this error message.

[image]

I just followed all the steps on that post page but not able to get the token. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The client id and secret you created are type web.  Which means that you need to have the proper redirect uri setup in the client when you created it.

I would suggest that you missed number 13 in the tutorial you are using.  You have not set a redirect uri for the client id that you are using in google developer console.

Comment: Hey DalmTo, Thanks for the comment but I set the redirect uri as it said in number 13. Do I have to change the type web into other types?

Comment: as log as you changed the client ids in Stage II - Creating a YouTube Refresh Token  its should be working

Comment: Thanks, finally I got the refresh token....but still having a problem with this. I made the `yt_oauth` command with tuber package in R and it seems unable to connect to the net with this error message...

`Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthcli`

Comment: Is this because of selecting the web type api?

Comment: There are two difrent types of clients on the developer console native (other) and web.  The login method for them is different.   urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob is only used for native applications.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I realized I managed to connect to the api by choosing 'other' instead of web application. Great!